# My laptop keyboard is messing up. Most characters when I type them either don't type or type random letters or symbols

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

Whenever I try to press any of the keys in my laptop, they either don't do anything or they type an entirely wrong character, it must be noted that not even the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> nor the <kbd>ALT</kbd> are working.

This a great problem and I cannot seem to figure out a way to fix it.  Here is a list of all of the keys that still do anything at all. The laptop model is a Windows 7 Compac CQ57 if it helps at all.

```
F3=5
F4=R
F6=`
F7=Q
W=1
E=4
Caps Lock=F1
S=Z
D=V
```

After looking up online, I've tried changing the language, changing keyboard formats, and even trying to start in safe mode (which can't be done as the arrows don't work either) but none of these seem to help so far

Comment: See if the behaves the same way outside of Windows (3rd party OS). Ensure keyboard is not full of coffee, Ensure keyboard is connected securely. Try a new/different keyboard. Unfortunately, as-is, there's not much of a question here, and no research effort shown.

Comment: It's a laptop, I cant diconnect the keyboard nor I have a usb one available right now.  I'm just trying to find a way to reset it or something alike - changing language to spanish also did not help, as the keyboard kept on acting in the same manner.  Also, I never drink anything near my laptop in fear of getting my nearby documents wet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can disconnect the keyboard.

Do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ls2lwQ6Rbs

Clean everything, and put it back to test.

But plugging in a USB keyboard first might be a good idea, in case it's a corrupted driver.

Answer (score 0):

first plug in a usb keyboard and see if everything works. If it does then you may need to replace the built in keyboard. watch Mark Wallace's video for the procedure.

There should be a part number on the back of the internal keyboard you can use this to find a new part on ebay or amazon.

While the internal keyboard is out you can still use the computer with the external keyboard.

If the external keyboard does not work then try typing on the internal keyboard in a bootable environment like a linux live disk. If this works then you may have a corrupt driver but corrupt keyboard drivers are rather rare.